# Grabbing place nearest to user's current location and saving it to Google Places API

Tags: ios, swift2, google-places-api

I want to get the nearest location to the current user using the Google Places API and save it, eventually creating an array of saved places. Since the google docs online are not very helpful I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do so myself. I've already have a CLLocationManager working fine but I'm at a loss when it comes to syncing everything.

Thank you!

When the user presses a button I want it to call a method and save the nearest current place... this is an example method of what I have so far.

```
func saveInfoTestMethod() {

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient?()

    placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (placeLikelihoods: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        for likelihood in placeLikelihoods!.likelihoods {
            if let likelihood = likelihood as? GMSPlaceLikelihood {
                let place = likelihood.place
                print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")

                //Somehow work below code into here

            }
        }
    })



    let userAddedPlace = GMSUserAddedPlace()


    placesClient?.addPlace(userAddedPlace, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in

        print(place!.name)
        print(place!.formattedAddress)
        print(place!.coordinate)
        print(place!.types)
        print(place!.phoneNumber)

    })



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "saving" a place?  Are you trying to keep a log of places that the user has been?  `addPlace` isn't going to help with that.  (It's for adding a Place to Google Maps, basically, so adding a place you received from the Google Places API isn't going to do anything useful.)

Comment: I mean retrieving a place from google API and saving them to an array within the app, either to Parse or Core Data. The documentation is pretty lacking on google's part so I feel a bit lost.

Comment: I added the Google Sign in frameworks/feature, Is it possible to save the user's current location/ names of nearby places to the current google account using this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to figure this out, the google docs doesn't include how to initialize the GMSPlacesClient so that's what was throwing me off, the code below works well.

```
func getInfoViaPlacesClient() {

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()

    placesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback { (likelihoodlist, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        for likelihood in likelihoodlist!.likelihoods {

            let nearestPlace = likelihoodlist!.likelihoods.first
            print(nearestPlace)

            if let likelihood = likelihood as? GMSPlaceLikelihood {
                let place = likelihood.place
                print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```